# Can't create new screens when logged into a server over ssh

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, unix

When physically connected to my "server" (typing commands from the desktop of a mid 2006 iMac), it gives the following output:

```
mac~$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/folders/ht/rhhsw0515vl_ym59683911400000gn/T/.screen.

bash$ screen -dmS foo
bash$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    4250.foo    (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/folders/ht/rhhsw0515vl_ym59683911400000gn/T/.screen.

bash$
```

Which is the behaviour one would expect. However, when executing the same commands over RSA-authenticated ssh the `screen -dmS foo` command doesn't seem to work:

```
remote-bash$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/folders/h4/_8scfsb54kd3mm7q6n9lq8nc0000gn/T/.screen.

remote-bash$ screen -dmS foo
remote-bash$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/folders/h4/_8scfsb54kd3mm7q6n9lq8nc0000gn/T/.screen.

remote-bash$
```

Upon trying the standard, option-free screen command, the entire shell hangs and can't be exited with ^C.

Note that I can see, attach to and kill screens launched on the server, but I can't launch them over ssh.

Is there an explanation for this inconsistency, or is the issue peculiar to my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem!

Turns out that, for some reason or another, screen cannot write without PAM being enabled. I'd previously read that, even if `PasswordAuthenticaiton`and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` are set to `no`, PAM is still a vulnerability, so I disabled it in the `/etc/sshd_config` file.

All it took was to change `UsePAM no`  to  `UsePAM yes` in `/etc/sshd_config`, and the command works as expected. I don't know if there's a way to use `screen` without PAM being enables, but I don't believe it's an especially grave security issue for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that the shell screen is launching when connected via ssh dies immediately for some reason. Try using

```
screen -LdmS foo
```

instead and then look at the contents of the file screenlog.0 to find out.

EDIT after OP comment:

it seems screen isn't able to start a shell. I guess your ssh server isn't setting the SHELL environment variable properly or your shell needs something else to run that your ssh server does not provide by default. Please check the output of

```
echo $SHELL
```

and then try to run the same shell by hand (i.e. execute the command you see in the output).

Also, there could be permission problems in the terminal. Under my OSX 10.9.5, just now, that is /dev/ttys000, in your case you can use the who command to find out yours. Screen needs write permission for the current user to that terminal. Now I read in your comment that the permissions in your case are:

```
crw--w---- 1 sandersfamily tty 16, 1 7 Mar 23:31 ttys001
```

Is "sandersfamily" the user you are logging in with via ssh? If not, then that's the problem.

Comment: I ran the command, but running `ls -a | grep screen` returned nothing in the ~/ or the / directories.

Comment: echoing `$SHELL` returns `/bin/bash` only

Comment: what if you launch a /bin/bash yourself instead of screen? Does it work?

Comment: launching /bin/bash works absolutely fine, it's just `screen` that behaves strangely.

Comment: What about the terminal permission bits? (see new edit in my reply).

Comment: In my case I'm logged in on `ttys001`, but running `cd bin && ls -l | grep screen` yields `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    638016  6 Dec  2011 screen`

Comment: It's not the screen command permissions you need to check, but the /dev/ttys001 file permissions. That aside, I don't understand how you reach the bin folder where the screen command resides.Is it meant to be /usr/bin? Or have you compiled screen yourself and installed it anywhere else?

Comment: `remote-host/dev/$ ls -l | grep ttys001`
yields
`crw--w----  1 sandersfamily  tty             16,   1  7 Mar 23:31 ttys001`